# Como mostrar Modal Bootstrap desde un metodo ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap, mvc

Este es mi metodo `ActionResult` el recibe los datos a traves de un form en mi `index.cshtml`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InsertUser(Person PersonData, User UserData)
{
    try
    {
        BusinessLogic.lnPerson _LNP = new BusinessLogic.lnPerson();
        PersonData.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
        PersonData.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
        int IdPerson = _LNP.InsertPerson(PersonData);
        PersonData.Id = IdPerson;
        UserData.Person = PersonData;
        UserData.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
        UserData.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
        BusinessLogic.lnUser _LNU = new BusinessLogic.lnUser();
        var create = _LNU.InsertUser(UserData);
        return View(); //Aqui que muestre la ventana de EXITOSO
    }
    catch
    {
        return View(); //Aqui que muestre la ventana de ERROR
    }
}
```

Tengo dos ventanas modal Bootstrap en mi `index.cshtml`. Como hago para llamar esas ventanas desde el controlador.

Comment: Yo añadiría una variable "showModal" al ViewBag en el que determinas si la modal se debe mostrar o no

Comment: Para llamar ventanas modales, lo correcto sería hacer uso de ajax, usando asp mvc 5, lo podes implementar usando PartialViews, cuando lo intentes, si tienes una duda un poco más concreta, podremos ayudarte a solucionarla!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes desde codigo servidor invocar una ventana que ejecuta en el cliente `html`.

Si podrias enviar un `flag` desde el action que actue sobre la `view` para mostrar el dialogo.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InsertUser(Person PersonData, User UserData)
{
     //resto codigo
     ViewBag.ShowDialog = true;
}
```

entonces en la view seria

```
@if(ViewBag.ShowDialog){
    <script>
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
    </script>
}
```

de esta forma generas `javascript` en base a una condicion que envias desde el servidor

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto seria hacer un metodo en el controlador tipo JsonResult, y realizar ajax. De esta forma se puede enviar objectos o lista para ser procesados y la respuesta ya podras desplegarla en algun modal.